Overriding a static method in Java (with an instance method)
class Main {
  public static void main(String [] args) { }
}

class Test extends Main {
  public void main(String [] args) { }
}

Why is something like this not allowed in Java? For example, they are static methods and instance methods, which I think can be distinguished.
I was not able to find any SO answers or docs on this.

no, it cannot be distinguished (not according actual Java Language Specification [JLS]) - new Test().main(null) could be used to call both methods) Why it is not allowed, because it is so specified - must ask specifier why, probably because a static method is considered a method available to the class, including instances of it - JLS 8.4.8.1. Overriding (by Instance Methods): "It is a compile-time error if the overridden method, mA, is a static method."(original emphasis)

simpler example, just calling main(...) from inside any instance method of Test

This question shouldn't be closed. The others only handle when you override by another static method.

Because thirty years ago, the Java designers decided so. Would they decide the same way again, if they were to decide today? We don’t know, but probably not. It starts with the inheritance of static methods. Change Main to an interface (and the other declaration to class Test implements Main) and the problem is gone, as static methods from interfaces are not inherited in the first place…

You cannot override the function main because it is the built in function which tells the compiler where to start reading code to compile.If it was any other function I think it could be possible to override it.

there is nothing special with the main method or the way it is handled, certainly not regarding the compiler - it is compiled as any other method. It just happens that the virtual machine invokes the static method called main when started. There is no difference to "any other"method
